# git completion with zsh: filenames with spaces aren't being escaped properly

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, git

Git completion:

I'm having difficulty with git's filename autocompletions on my system. I'm using `zsh` (5.0.5) with `git` (1.9.3) on OS X (10.9.3). Both `zsh` and `git` have been installed via homebrew. (Full version output are at the bottom of the post.)

`git`'s filename completion isn't inserting spaces like I expect. When I type the name of a file with a space in the name, the shell inserts the filename without spaces escaped. `zsh`'s built-in completion doesn't do this, but `git`'s does.

Here's an example of what I'm seeing.

I have a repository with a few files with spaces in their names.

```
% ls -la
test
test four - latest.txt
test three.txt
test two
```

The shell backslash escapes the filenames as expected when I use tab completion to insert the file name.

```
% echo "testing" >> test<tab>
```

autocompletes to this after hitting tab three times.

```
% echo "testing" >> test\ four\ -\ latest.txt
––– file
test                       test\ four\ -\ latest.txt  test\ three.txt            test\ two
```

`git status` shows these filenames in quotes (it totally understands what's up):

```
% git status --short
 M test
 M "test four - latest.txt"
 M "test three.txt"
 M "test two"
```

but when I try to `git add` with tab autocompletion, it goes sideways.

```
% git add test<tab>
```

results in this after hitting tab three times:

```
% git add test four - latest.txt
test                    test four - latest.txt  test three.txt          test two
```

I've tried regressing this a bit: my dotfiles are in version control, so I've tried `zsh 4.3.15`, `git 1.8.3`, and my dotfiles from a year ago, when I'm nearly certain this worked. Weirdly, this setup was still broken.

I *have* narrowed it down to the `_git` completion file that is being sourced from `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions`:

```
% echo $FPATH
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions:/usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.0.5/share/zsh/functions
% ls -l /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
_git@ -> ../../../Cellar/git/1.9.3/share/zsh/site-functions/_git
_hg@ -> ../../../Cellar/mercurial/3.0/share/zsh/site-functions/_hg
_j@ -> ../../../Cellar/autojump/21.7.1/share/zsh/site-functions/_j
git-completion.bash@ -> ../../../Cellar/git/1.9.3/share/zsh/site-functions/git-completion.bash
go@ -> ../../../Cellar/go/HEAD/share/zsh/site-functions/go
```

If I manually change `$FPATH` before my `.zshrc` runs `compinit` (or simply remove the `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_git` symbolic link), then completions fall back to `zsh` and work as expected.

The `zsh` completion without `_git`:

```
% git add test<tab>
```

hitting tab three times produces correct results:

```
% git add test\ four\ -\ latest.txt
––– modified file
test                       test\ four\ -\ latest.txt  test\ three.txt            test\ two
```

Side note: I've tried removing the `git-completion.bash` link, and it just totally breaks things:

```
% git add test<tab>
```

produces this busted-ness:

```
% git add test__git_zsh_bash_func:9: command not found: __git_aliased_command
    git add test
––– file
test                       test\ four\ -\ latest.txt  test\ three.txt            test\ two
```

---

I **really** want to get this working properly: the rest of the `_git` completions were great because they're more repo-aware than the `zsh` ones, but I need filenames with spaces or other special characters to be properly escaped.

---

Software versions:

```
% zsh --version
zsh 5.0.5 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0)

% git --version
git version 1.9.3

% sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.9.3
BuildVersion:   13D65
```

---

I've uploaded the `_git` and `git-completion.bash` files: [git-completion.bash](http://cl.ly/code/153v2t142i2G) and [_git](http://cl.ly/code/423e0i1X1p29) (renamed to `_git.sh` so CloudApp will make it viewable in the browser.)

Comment: For the non-OSX users in the audience, could you link to some place where we can download the completions that ship with your git package?

Comment: Sure: _git (renamed to _git.sh for CloudApp): http://cl.ly/code/423e0i1X1p29 and git-completion.bash: http://cl.ly/code/153v2t142i2G

Comment: I had a glance at `_git`. The calls to `compadd -Q` look weird: `-Q` means “don't quote special characters”. Try removing `-Q` from the `compadd` calls.

Comment: Interesting, that seems to fix it. I'm also finding that I prefer the completions I'm getting when I move the _git file aside, but I'm having trouble understanding where those are coming from.

Comment: i.e. when I munge `FPATH` to drop the `_git` completions and just use `zsh`'s built-ins, those are way better. But somewhere in the shell path loading process, it's prepending `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions` to `FPATH` which squashes the `zsh` functions in `/usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.0.5/share/zsh/functions`.

Comment: I'm fairly sure the problem is due to `zsh`'s default behavior of not word-splitting command-substitution results. In fact - the `\bs` escape isn't necessary - or is futile, depending on how you look at it. Set `"SH_WORD_SPLIT"` http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq03.html

Comment: Alternatively edit the bash completion functions to output like `${=$(completion)}` or whatever it is that they return.

Comment: Setting `setopt SH_WORD_SPLIT` doesn't seem to affect the completions at all. (I tried a quick test via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715388/variable-expansion-is-different-in-zsh-from-that-in-bash to make sure it was being set correctly)

Comment: Where do you set it? I would think it wouldn't affect a prompt command if you just set it at the prompt or even in your zshrc. You'll probably need to edit the functions that you're trying to run. I expect their return comes in the form of a command substitution into an `eval`ed variable somewhere on the way to `$PROMPT-COMMAND.` But, really, these are *bash* completions - can you not use *zsh* completions?

Comment: I hacked around this by [disabling the unwanted completion](https://github.com/wincent/wincent/commit/cecd77b6782c4029cce65724c5fa0d47cf233d5c).

Comment: @wincent which completion, and what file?

Comment: @cbowns: the one installed by Homebrew Git. The linked commit shows the exact file.

Comment: Removing the all the `-Q` from `compadd` fixes this, but creates another problem: if you type in `git commit --am<TAB>` expecting `git commit --amend`, you get  `git commit --amend\ ` instead.

To make it work, only remove -Q from the `__gitcomp_file ()` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bug is mentioned on the [mailing list](https://marc.info/?l=git&m=147265392409883&w=2).

The fix is to edit the file `git-completion.zsh` and remove the `-Q` option from `compadd`, in in `__gitcomp_file`.

```
--- i/contrib/completion/git-completion.zsh
+++ w/contrib/completion/git-completion.zsh
@@ -90,7 +90,7 @@ __gitcomp_file ()

    local IFS=$'\n'
    compset -P '*[=:]'
-   compadd -Q -p "${2-}" -f -- ${=1} && _ret=0
+   compadd -p "${2-}" -f -- ${=1} && _ret=0
 }

 __git_zsh_bash_func ()
```

This file is installed from the `contrib/completion` directory, and its path may vary with your package manager. If you installed with homebrew on macOS, it's located in `/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.10.2/share/zsh/site-functions`.

Comment: The error about `__git_aliased_command` is because the share directory changed name to git-core (at least on FreeBSD), which causes it to not find `git-completion.bash`. If you change the first location on line 33 to a hardcoded `/usr/local/share/git-core/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash` it works again.

Comment: There's an `echo` in that file just above these function definitions, and the lack of appearance of it in my shell (and some adjacent code when testing) suggests these completions aren't even used: ``if [[ -n ${ZSH_VERSION-} ]]; then
 echo "WARNING: this script is deprecated, please see git-completion.zsh" 1>&2
``

Comment: This worked for me (git 2.18, zsh 5.4.2 osx) when I changed `compadd -Q` -> `compadd` for all instances in `_git` and `git-completion.bash` in the folder `/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.18.0/share/zsh/site-functions/` of my brew git installation. Thank you!!!